# Update column according max value from other column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Taking the max value of column 'time', I need update the column 'register' group by Identification column, set register = 1 and the rest register = 0

Initial table:

```
Identification | time | register
1              |  0       | 0
1              |  7       | 0
1              |  3       | 0
2              |  10      | 0
2              |  5       | 0
2              |  0       | 0
3              |  6       | 0
3              |  5       | 0
3              |  0       | 0
```

Ending table:

```
Identification | time     | register
1              |  0       | 0
1              |  7       | 1
1              |  3       | 0
2              |  10      | 1
2              |  5       | 0
2              |  0       | 0
3              |  6       | 1
3              |  5       | 0
3              |  0       | 0
```

In SQL 2017, the table contains thousand of registers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want a `CASE` expression and a windowed `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT Identification,
       [time],
       CASE [time] WHEN MAX([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY Identification) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS register
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```